# Is there a formula for the number of labeled forests with $k$ components on $n$ vertices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Cayley's formula states that the number of labeled trees on $n$ vertices is $n^{n-2}$. My question is: Is there a generalization of this formula for forests?

Let $f_{n,k}$ denote the number of forests with $k$ connected components on $n$ vertices. For example, $f_{n,1} = n^{n-2}$ by Cayley's formula and $f_{n,n-1} = \binom{n}{2}$. Is there a known closed formula for $f_{n,k}$? If not, is there an asymptotic formula?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A formula as a single sum is 
$$f_{n,k} = \binom nk \sum_{i=0}^k  \left(-\frac12\right)^i (k+i)\,i!\, \binom{k}{i}\binom{n-k}{i} n^{n-k-i-1}.$$
This formula can be found in J. W. Moon's *Counting Labelled Trees*, Theorem 4.1. He attributes it to A. Rényi, *Some remarks on the theory of trees*, Publications of the Mathematical Institute of the Hungarian Academy of Sciences 4 (1959), 73--85.

To prove it, let $T= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{n-1} x^n/n!$ be the exponential generating function for rooted trees and let $U=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{n-2} x^n/n!$ be the exponential generating function for unrooted trees. It is well known that 
$$T^k = k! \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom nk k n^{n-k-1}\frac{x^n}{n!}.\tag{$*$}$$
Then $U = T-T^2/2$ so the exponential generating for forests of $k$ trees is 
$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty f_{n,k} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{U^n}{n!}=\frac{(T-T^2/2)^k}{k!},$$
and the formula for $f_{n,k}$ follows by expanding the right side by the binomial theorem and using $(*)$.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward formula: $f_{n,k}$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in
$$\frac{n!}{k!}\cdot\left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^{i-2}x^i}{i!}\right)^k$$
(clearly, the sum here can be restricted to first $n$ terms).

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that more than https://oeis.org/A105599 is known.

The formula given in Bollobas is
$$
\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{j=0}^m \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^j \binom{m}{j}\binom{n-1}{m+j-1}n^{n-m-j}(m+j)!,
$$
where $n$ is the number of vertices and $m$ is the number of components.

Answer (score 0):

The one below is not really a closed formula, but I post it for the sake of completeness.

$$\frac{n!}{k!} \sum_{\substack{n_1+\dots+n_k=n \\ n_i\geq 1}} \prod\limits_{j=1}^m \frac{n_j^{n_j-2}}{n_j!}$$

The subscript of the summation is a fixed-length integer partition of $n$ with a lower bound on the terms; a quick google search only lead me to two separate questions dealing with [fixed-length partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54635/integer-partition-with-fixed-number-of-summands-but-without-order) and with [lower bounds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069639/partition-with-minimum-size-of-parts).

The original Russian paper, where the formula appears, can be found [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mzm&paperid=4331&option_lang=eng), and an English transcript [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01158847).

(Britikov, V. E. Asymptotics of the number of forests made up of nonrooted trees. (Russian) Mat. Zametki 43 (1988), no. 5, 672–684, 703; translation in Math. Notes 43 (1988), no. 5-6, 387–394)